# If a key is pressed press another one too in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do the following in javascript :

If "B" is pressed > Press "C" automatically

How to achieve this condition ? e.keyCode == 66 is B

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 66) { 
          
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to trigger the enter key after pressing B key so it can access automatically to a link I have. Without going manually and clicking on it.

Comment: Why not trigger the click event directly? Seems like a roundabout and fragile approach

Comment: @charlietfl , okay, how ?

Comment: $(selector).click()

Comment: Tried it didn't work :/

Comment: Time for you to start including runnable [mcve]s in your questions then.

Comment: The problem is that I have a whole code with sliders and stuff and I tried simplifying my issue here.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("keypress", e => {
        if (e.which == 66) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var f = $.Event("keypress", {which: 13});
            $(document).trigger(f);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, unfortunally it doesn't work. I replaced x with 13 so it can trigger enter but nothing.

Comment: Updated answer with a different method.

Comment: Made a couple more edits. Crossing my fingers for you :)

Comment: Now it doesn't even acknowledge the "B" key for some reason.

Comment: Well...at least I know it's running the funciton :/  `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action for the "B" key. I put that in there to prevent "B" from doing anything, then triggering the "Enter" key right after. If you remove that line, the "B" key will work again.

Comment: Now the B is working with your code, I guess I mistyped something. Anyway the enter is till not working, the B is working. I feel you are close.